# Add random string to ssh command so the instance can be identified with ps

Tags: linux, openssh

I am opening a ssh tunnel with `ssh -f -N -L ...`

There can be multiple instances opened like this at once.

I would like to add information to the ssh command so I can find it with `ps` piped to grep.

Is there a way to add data to the command so that it shows up on `ps aux

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't it be sufficient to find it by its PID? (In *bash*, PID can be simply returned like this:)

```
ssh -f -N -L ... & echo $!
```